# How do I convert java ArrayList<Double> to equivalent Scala?

Tags: scala

So far I have

```
def toDoubleArray(list: ArrayList<Double>): Array[Double] {
  ...
}
```

Which is not compiling and is underlined but giving a very cryptic error message

Comment: Could it be the angle brackets? Generics use square brackets in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def toDoubleArray(list: ArrayList[Double]): Array[Double] = list.toArray
```

import will allow automatic conversion of Java ArrayList to scala <strike>ListBuffer</strike> ArrayBuffer

<strike>More generic solution:</strike>

```
def [T] toDoubleArray(list: ArrayList[T]): Array[T] = list.toArray
```

But in reality you don't even need a function to do that.

Comment: `ArrayList` goes to `ArrayBuffer`.  `LinkedList` goes to `ListBuffer`.

Comment: Agree... it doesn't. I crossed it out